# Program to remove disliked words using VECTORS in C++? [This is a "Try This" quesn in PPP Chapter 4]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

```
#include "..//..//std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
     vector<string>disliked ;
     cout<<" Enter the words you don't like :- ";
     string dis;
     while(cin>>dis)
         {disliked.push_back(dis);
          cout<<"To terminate the input press ctrl+Z";
         }
     cout<<"Enter a sentence :-";
     vector<string>sentence;
     string word;

     while(cin>>word)
         {
          sentence.push_back(word);
          cout<<"To terminate the input press ctrl+Z";
         }
     for(unsigned int i=0;i<sentence.size();i++)
          {for(unsigned int n=0;n<disliked.size();n++)
              {if (sentence[i] == disliked[n])
               sentence[i] = "Bleep";
              }
          cout<<sentence[i];
          }
}
```

When I run the program the execution stops after the first input. It doesn't let me enter the words into the sentence vector.

Comment: Please copy/paste output as text into the question, not as a screenshot image.  In fact, you should avoid using screenshots, unless there's absolutely *no other alternative*.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this was my first question. Will take care of it future.

Comment: You should do that on this question, too.  Having obvious issues like this with your question will encourage downvoting.  If you get too many downvotes, you may be banned from asking questions on Stack Exchange.  Check out this question and the answers on [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) to make sure that this doesn't happen to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an input stream receives an end-of-file condition, all further attempts to read from the input stream, and not just the first attempt, will fail with an end-of-file condition.

So, when you used CTRL-Z to send an end-of-file on standard input, you continued to receive an end-of-file condition on the input stream when you attempted to read more input from it.

Although there may or may not be ways to clear an end-of-file condition from an interactive terminal, the easiest thing to do is to find some other way to signal the end of the first set of inputs, other than CTRL-Z for an end of file.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but since the input type is string  even if I am entering 23 or whatever it accepts it into dis and the loop continues . Is there any other way?

Comment: Got it.Thanks. @Sam